# I have a row vector and I would like to add it onto the end of a matrix

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have lots of FFT data and I would like to place it all into a 2-dimensional array. Each new entry looks like: `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...]`  (and so on, for 1200 columns).

And I would like to add it to the end (the bottom of a matrix) e.g.:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  ... ]             <-- add here please
```

I was wondering how I should go about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean basic concatenation

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...];
>> b = [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...];
>> c = [a; b]
c = 
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ...
   2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...
```

If you do this in a loop, it is a good habit to pre-allocate the matrix beforehand:

```
>> a = zeros(5);
>> for i = 1:5
>>     a(i, :) = randi(10,1,5);
>> end
a =
     3     6    10    10     2
    10    10     5     9     2
     5    10     8    10     7
     1     9    10     7     8
     8     4     7     2     8
```

While it is technically possible to 'grow' the array (as in `a = [a; randi(10,1,5)]`), it is not advisable to do this inside loops -- this makes them really much slower.

Comment: cheers, this post was helpful. I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so

Comment: If you want, you can unaccept your own answer, and accept mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [cat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) for concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Cheers guys, I have managed to solve my problem using a different solution. I will share my answer in case anybody in the future stumbles upon this.

```
i=1;
A=zeros(m,n);
while(i<m)
  (do some FFT stuff here)
  A(i,1:n)=(F.*conj(F))';       %where F is the temporary vector for storing FFT results
  i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: Why don't you use a for-loop?